# Node.js won't shut down after executing log4js

Tags: javascript, node.js, cassandra

My nodejs program does not end process if I use log4js with a Cassandra appender.

Here is an easy sample :

```js
var config = require('./scripts/configuration.js');

var log4js = require('log4js');

/* Logger configuration */
log4js.configure({
    appenders: {
        filelog: { type: 'file', filename: 'errors.log' },
        syslog: { type: './scripts/test-appender-cassandra.js', nodes: config.cassandra.contactPoints, keyspace: config.cassandra.keyspace, table: 'system_logs' }
    },
    categories: {
        file: { appenders: ['filelog'], level: 'error' },
        another: { appenders: ['syslog'], level: 'error' },
        default: { appenders: ['syslog'], level: 'error' }
    }
});
var logger = log4js.getLogger('syslog');

console.log('end');
```

In my real program, I do use Promise and currently I use process.exit(1) to exit but it's not the proper way.

Edit: The problem seems to be linked to the Cassandra appender. It maintains an open connection to Cassandra. I can not close/shutdown it.

Answer (score 0):

Just a disclaimer, I have not used log4js.

Have you tried to call 
`log4js.shutdown(cb)`
?